# Continuous bijection such that induces homomorphism is no bijection

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Give an example of a continuous bijection $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ between path-connected spaces such that the induced homomorphism $\phi_{*}: \pi_1(X, x) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y, \phi(x))$ on fundamental groups is not a bijection.

**Attempt:** I was thinking of taking a map $$ S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1 $$ but I'm not sure how to get a bijection, such that the induced homomorphism is not a bijection. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=[0,2\pi)$ and $Y=S^1$ and let $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ be the quotient map. Then, $p|_X$ is continuous and bijective, but $X$ is contractible while $Y$ has a nontrivial fundamental group.

Comment: What is $\pi$ precisely? What are the equivalence classes?

Comment: It's $\theta\mapsto \exp(i\theta)$ if you want a formula.

Comment: you might want to use a symbol other than $\pi$ for your map since your answer also contains the number $\pi$

Comment: ...Right you are.